# How can I change the space between <ul> and <li> elements?

Tags: html, css

I am going nuts with the probably easiest css issue ever. I just want to add some margin between a `<ul>` and `<li>` element. I use a dropdown when hovered at a category.

I tried to add `margin-top` in each css class/element I have, but there is no effect at all. Do I miss a class here or is there any workaround solution?

This is what I thought is the working solution, but it doesn't append a margin:

```
#sidebar .subbar li:first-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">Dasocc</a>
      </header>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="countries"><img src="{% static "images/germany.png" %}" alt="germany">1. Bundesliga
          <ul class="subbar">
            <li><a class="team" id="69">FC Bayern München</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="70">Borussia Dortmund</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="73">Bayer 04 Leverkusen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="74">RB Leipzig</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">VfL Wolfsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Freiburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Eintracht Frankfurt</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Borussia M. Gladbach</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Schalke 04</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">TSG 1899 Hoffenheim</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Union Berlin</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Fortuna Düsseldorf</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SV Werder Bremen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Köln</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Paderborn</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Augsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Hertha BSC Berlin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Länderkategorien untereinander */
#sidebar .nav .countries {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

/* hovered Team */
#sidebar .nav a:hover {
  color: #FF5B5B;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000481;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.4em #000481;
}

/* angeklicktes Team */
#sidebar .subbar .team.active {
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #000481;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0.4em #000481;
}

/* Untermenü ausblenden, um dropdown Effekt zu aktivieren */
#sidebar .subbar {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Dropdownmenu Funktion */
#sidebar .countries:hover .subbar {
  display: table-row;
  list-style: none;
}

/* Style Menüpunkte Countries */
.countries {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

/* Einzelne List-Container in Submenü */
#sidebar .subbar li {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Einzelne Teamnamen in Submenü */

#sidebar .subbar .team {
  display:table-cell;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 33px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
´´´
```

Comment: Where exacly does the extra space needs to be? i don't fully understand the question

Comment: @RamondeVries between the Category "1. Bundesliga" and the first element of the dropdown menue

Comment: try giving padding to subbar element `#sidebar .subbar{padding-top: 10px}`

Comment: @Sim1-81 already included in my code, no effect..

Comment: could you provide the full code? i'm missing some parts making debugging a guess situation

Comment: any reason you use display table-row to show the subbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that on the `:hover` event you are displaying the `<ul>` as a `table-row`:

```
#sidebar .countries:hover .subbar {
  display: table-row;
  ...
```

Actually, if you display it as a `block` then you will find that it displays with the margin you have specified, as you'd expect:

```
#sidebar .countries:hover .subbar {
  display: block;
  ...
```

The below snippet shows it (although it renders poorly):

```css
#sidebar {
background-color: blue;
}

/* Länderkategorien untereinander */
#sidebar .nav .countries {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

/* hovered Team */
#sidebar .nav a:hover {
  color: #FF5B5B;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000481;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.4em #000481;
}

/* angeklicktes Team */
#sidebar .subbar .team.active {
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #000481;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0.4em #000481;
}

/* Untermenü ausblenden, um dropdown Effekt zu aktivieren */
#sidebar .subbar {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Dropdownmenu Funktion */
#sidebar .countries:hover .subbar {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

/* Style Menüpunkte Countries */
.countries {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

/* Einzelne List-Container in Submenü */
#sidebar .subbar li {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Einzelne Teamnamen in Submenü */

#sidebar .subbar .team {
  display:table-cell;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 33px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <header>
    <a href="#">Dasocc</a>
  </header>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="countries"><img src="" alt="germany">1. Bundesliga
      <ul class="subbar">
        <li><a class="team" id="69">FC Bayern München</a></li>
        <li><a class="team" id="70">Borussia Dortmund</a></li>
        <li><a class="team" id="73">Bayer 04 Leverkusen</a></li>
        <li><a class="team" id="74">RB Leipzig</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">VfL Wolfsburg</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">SC Freiburg</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">Eintracht Frankfurt</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">Borussia M. Gladbach</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">FC Schalke 04</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">TSG 1899 Hoffenheim</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">1. FC Union Berlin</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">Fortuna Düsseldorf</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">SV Werder Bremen</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">1. FC Köln</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">SC Paderborn</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">FC Augsburg</a></li>
        <li><a class="team">Hertha BSC Berlin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your css file.

```
.team{
 padding-left:20px;
}
```

or

```
.team{
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

simple

Comment: Don't forget to tick this as the answer if it's what worked for you @phanti

Answer (score 1):

solved just adding display block and padding top to .subbar element

```css
* Dropdownmenu Funktion */
#sidebar .countries:hover .subbar {
  display: table-row;
  list-style: none;
  
}

/* Style Menüpunkte Countries */
.countries {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

/* Einzelne List-Container in Submenü */
#sidebar .subbar{
display: block;
padding-top:40px
}
#sidebar .subbar li {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color:#000 !important
}
a{
color: #000
/* Einzelne Teamnamen in Submenü */

#sidebar .subbar .team {
  display:table-cell;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 33px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">Dasocc</a>
      </header>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="countries"><img src="{% static "images/germany.png" %}" alt="germany">1. Bundesliga
          <ul class="subbar">
            <li><a class="team" id="69">FC Bayern München</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="70">Borussia Dortmund</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="73">Bayer 04 Leverkusen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="74">RB Leipzig</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">VfL Wolfsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Freiburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Eintracht Frankfurt</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Borussia M. Gladbach</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Schalke 04</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">TSG 1899 Hoffenheim</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Union Berlin</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Fortuna Düsseldorf</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SV Werder Bremen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Köln</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Paderborn</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Augsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Hertha BSC Berlin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```